# Count all nonwhite character

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count number of items in given table. But table may consist cell with different whitespace chars.

I would like to do count, but only consider cell with letters and number.

I was trying to do

```
COUNTIF(<range>, "?*")
```

Is there any list of available wildchars provided by google-spreadsheet ? I need "*" but matching only numbers and letters.

Comment: whitechar = whitespace?

Comment: Good point. I mean whitespace chars. I edited the question.

Comment: I think table can contain only empty cell or `enter` or multiple `space`. So yes, I want every cell containing letters OR numbers. 
Or from the opposite side. I want everything which is not empty or only containing spaces, new lines or other whitespace "junk".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use regexmatch to match letters or digits ?

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(N(regexmatch(A2:L18&"", "\w|\d"))))
```

Change the range to suit.

See also [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/open-school.be/spreadsheets/d/1tveECu87ej5NYpSlAro7WMShxCeJ6tQ8hgvKaHsU2LY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(sum(N(regexmatch(B3:J37&"", "w|d"))))` is returning "1".

Could you explain little bit what is it doing ?

Comment: I updated the formula. The regexmatch checks the range for letters (\w) or ("|") digits (\d). N() converts the booleans (true, false) to 1, 0.